# Пустые строки после import-ов pep8

Tags: python, pep8

Сколько должно быть пустых строк после impor-ов перед CONST?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

****Ответ:**** *одна строка должна быть "после impor-ов перед CONST".*

**Обоснование:** PEP-8 не определяет количества пустых строк в субглавах, посвященных constants или import. Про них пишут только в субглаве Blank Lines https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#blank-lines. И там написано, что два пропуска требуются только для top-level function and class definitions, да допустимы для отделения групп связанных функций. Значит, должен быть пропуск в одну строку.

**Проверка:** PyCharm содержит опцию "Reformat the file". Написав `CONST = 5` без пропуска после `import` и применив эту опцию к файлу, получаем в результате одну пропускаемую строку.